# How do you reverse a skew transformation in the Flash IDE?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, transformation, skew

Place a 100px by 100px box on the stage (not a movieclip, just a simple shape).
[image]

Now apply a vertical skew of 30 degrees. You should get this...
[image]

Click outside of the shape to release the transformation data. The degrees for skew resets to 0 (this is expected), see image below
[image]

**But** What skew would you apply to the shape to return it to its original shape. Initially I would've thought it was -30 in the vertical skew, but this seems to return a weird hybrid shape.. See below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked it out for my setup (CS5 Flash). The steps are in the diagram, but work along the lines of:

1. Set the scaleX to **(1/cos([skew amount])) * 100**. The skew amount needs to be converted to radians.
2. Set the v-skew to **-[skew amount]**
3. Release the shape, then reselect it (all transformation data would be reset)
4. Set the scaleX to **(1/cos([skew amount])) * 100**. Yes, you need to do it twice

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it, and the answer was surprisingly obvious...though don't feel bad, I overlook the obvious a LOT!

Click the object, and set the skew angle back to 0 degrees.

And, +1 for an excellently illustrated question!

**EDIT:** Talked to my animator. She tried the steps in the question, and -30 worked, strangely enough. She uses Flash CS4. As a possible alternative, she suggested making the drawing a symbol, and then skewing that. That way, you can always go back to the original. Not sure if that helps, but hopefully it does you (or someone).

Comment: I don't think works for a basic shape (not a movieclip, and not a sprite)? Thanks though

Comment: I did it with a basic shape, not a movieclip or a sprite. I checked that.

Comment: I wish it were this simple, but are you sure you are clicking outside the shape to reset the transformation data as per my line "Click outside of the shape to release the transformation data. The degrees for skew resets to 0 (this is expected), see image below" So the skew is 0 degrees, so updating it to 0 degrees as per your suggestion won't work. Honestly I wish it did, but it doesn't. I thank you for your help regardless though

Comment: I was meticulously careful to ensure that I recreated your problem exactly. I not only recreated the issue, but also the solution. To repeat, I followed your instructions exactly. After clicking outside the shade, CLICK THE SHAPE AGAIN (emphasizing, not shouting there) and set the skew angle on it to 0. I tried this and it works. If this does not work for you, there must be another component of your code (or a bug/glitch in the software or computer) which is affecting this.

Comment: Well this is confusing, we must be using a different version of Flash or the Adobe suite, or as you said different computer setups. Thankyou, and I appreciate your help

Comment: Not sure if it'll be helpful (possibly not), but I talked to my animator and got a suggestion from her. She doesn't know that it'll help you, but I'll toss it out there just in case.

Comment: Hey JasonMC - sorry that I could use your answer, I ended up coming with another way. Thanks for help though!